# jQueryUI Accordion Header CSS Problem

Tags: css, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion header like so,

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="header1"><a href="#">Stuff: <span id="text">Text </span></a></h3>
```

and upon some event happening, I change the colour of `<span id="text">`.

```
$("h3 #text).css("color","red");
```

What I want to do is change the colour back to the default accordion header colours. I can change it back to its default colour, but then it doesn't change colour when you hover over it or click it.

Is there a way to change its class or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). You want something like:

```
$("h3 #text).mouseEnter(function{$("h3 #text).toggleClass("header1Active");});
$("h3 #text).mouseLeave(function{$("h3 #text).toggleClass("header1Active");});
```

Where you have some css:

```
h3.header1Active {
    color: red
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out and was about to answer my own question!